# How to apply border to switch compact in android

Tags: android, switch-statement, border

Here is the below code that I applied for `switchcompact` and I am able to get without border , but my requirement is to apply border similar to the image below

mylayout.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/switch_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch_email"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:theme="@style/SwitchStyle"/>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="SwitchStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/blue_action_bar</item>
    <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/gray</item>
```

but I need a image similar to like this [image: Image needed like this]

How to apply the border for switch compact like this to render.

Answer (score 0):

I realised this solution:

1. Prepare two drawables for switched on and switched off states of track and one for thumb:
   switch_track_on.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
        <corners android:radius="18dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/white" />
        <size android:width="36dp" android:height="@dimen/dp20" />
    </shape>
```

switch_track_off.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/gray2" />
        <corners android:radius="18dp" />
        <size android:width="36dp" android:height="@dimen/dp20" />
    </shape>
```

switch_thumb.xml

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
        <size android:width="@dimen/dp16" android:height="@dimen/dp16" />
    </shape>
```

2. Make track of SwitchCompat transparent and set thumb drawable with styles:

```
    <style name="CustomSwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="trackTint">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_thumb</item>
        <item name="thumbElevation">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

3. Put ImageView with track drawable and SwitchCompat into RelativeLayout:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_subscribe_item_switch_wrap"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp20"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp36">
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/switch_track_on"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp36"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp20"
            android:alpha="1"
            android:src="@drawable/switch_track_on"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/switch_track_off"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dp36"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp20"
            android:alpha="0"
            android:src="@drawable/switch_track_off"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:id="@+id/profile_subscribe_item_switch"
            style="@style/CustomSwitch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            app:switchPadding="0dp"
            app:showText="false" />
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

4. And finally add setOnCheckedChangeListener to SwitchCompat and animate track ImageViews alpha value depending on isChecked value.